# Metaplex storefront on vercel perpetual loading problem

Tags: solana, metaplex

I am having problem loading metaplex store. I did a direct fork from the main metaplex-foundation github master and deployed it on Vercel via their instructions here: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/blob/master/docs/deploy.md

It builds without errors, but when I load the site, it just keeps loading forever and wallet cannot be accessed or connected nor the site be accessible.

I followed all instructions from their link above and ensured I have the address in the.env.
I even added a URL in a new CNAME file I added in packages/web folder, from previous experience.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The current version is slow. Like very very very slow and loads hundreds of MB on every page load.
Not sure which code changes are made by the projects where the storefront is working ok.
If you do not want to invest much time into it it might be worth waiting for a v2.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, metaplex acknowledges that the current storefront (v1) has quite a few issues that are impacting users. No further fixes will be forthcoming given that the storefront has been officially deprecated as of May 2022. With that out of the way, a high level overview of the issue you are describing is as follows:

1. when you start a storefront (SF) that has no auctions, it needs to scan quite a bit of data to figure out what it needs to display. This scan includes a few chunky calls to the RPC that may or may not work depending on the state of the network. This step is also a bit buggy and can end up in an infinite loading loop.
2. when you fire up the first auction, SF creates a storeindexer object on the chain. This object is used to index the first auction and all the subsequent auctions.
3. if SF finds a storeindexer object on startup, it bypasses all the madness in step (1) and instead uses the storeindexer to figure out what data is needed. That doesn’t require any gPA (getProgramAccount) calls either which is nice.
4. it’s a bit of a catch-22 because in order to start the first auction you need the storefront, but you also need an auction to avoid the loading problem in step (1).

After the first auction is up you should be able to resume using your SF as normal.

You may try this version of the storefront to get around the infinite loading problem. It's quite barebones in terms of functionality and there is an issue with SPL tokens that have decimals other than 9.  However it does get around the infinite loading problem and you should be able to list your first auction with it.

https://github.com/neftworld/metaplex-storefront-v1

However, **STOREFRONT IS DEPRECATED SO CAVEAT EMPTOR**